# Extract data from Curl POST request

Tags: java, servlets, post, curl

I am making  a POST request using curl as follows

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-X POST \
-d '{ "name": "PhoneName", "description": "Phone Description!", "details": { "imeiNumber": "123456789123456", "phoneNumber": "9999999999"}}' \
-k \
http://test.domain.com/myTestServer/devices
```

But in the servlet I am not able to get any of the data posted.

```
public void devices(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Got Request for devices");
    System.out.println("Request is : "+ request);
    System.out.println("Name : " + request.getParameter("name"));   //gives null
    System.out.println("description : " + request.getParameter("description")); //gives null
    Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();   //Empty Enumeration
    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()){
        String paramName = paramNames.nextElement();
        System.out.println(paramName + " : " + request.getParameter(paramName));

    }

}
```

Any suggestions? Also a better way to get data inside data like `"details": { "imeiNumber": "123456789123456", "phoneNumber": "9999999999"}` ?

Comment: It's a JSON string, can you use JSON or GSON?

Comment: Yeah looks like we cannot simply unmarshall  it. Trying GSON library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> -d '{ "name": "PhoneName", "description": "Phone Description!", "details": { "imeiNumber": "123456789123456", "phoneNumber": "9999999999"}}' \

pushes the input json into POST request payload.
And you CANNOT simply unmarshall the input json attributes using their names and hence you get

```
System.out.println("Name : " + request.getParameter("name"));   //gives null
```

`null` values for such statements.

You need to read the POST request payload from your `HttpServletRequest` object and then should use json parser to parse it to get the attribute values.

You can read the entire POST request payload like this:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
            stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } else {
        stringBuilder.append("");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw ex;
} finally {
    if (bufferedReader != null) {
        try {
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}

body = stringBuilder.toString();
```

Now you should get your input json in variable body. Now use a json parser to get the attribues value, for example like this:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject obj = parser.parse(body).getAsJsonObject();
String name = obj.get("name").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions? Also a better way to get data inside data like "details": { "imeiNumber": "123456789123456", "phoneNumber": "9999999999"}

## It's a Suggestion, don't treat it as Solution

Sorry, I don't have any idea about curl, but I can help you to parse the JSON string using [GSON library](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Just enclose the above JSON string inside `{...}` and parse it into Java object as illustrated in below sample code.
Sample code:

```
class Details {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private PhoneNumberDetails details;
    // getter & setter  
}


class PhoneNumberDetails{
    private String imeiNumber;
    private String phoneNumber;
    // getter & setter    
}

String json = "{ \"name\": \"PhoneName\", \"description\": \"Phone Description!\", \"details\": { \"imeiNumber\": \"123456789123456\", \"phoneNumber\": \"9999999999\"}}";
Details data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Details.class);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

output:

```
{
  "name": "PhoneName",
  "description": "Phone Description!",
  "details": {
    "imeiNumber": "123456789123456",
    "phoneNumber": "9999999999"
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not mention why the input json is not received properly? You have simply posted how to parse a json.

Comment: Read the question again and try to understand it before answering.

Comment: I think I should delete my post that is not relevant as per @Juned Ahsan because there are some guys that never like suggestion, They always looks for solution. **Suggestion** are not accepted at all.

Comment: @AniketThakur Please ask for solution not for Suggestion.

Comment: `Please ask for solution`.. Really? Solutions don't really matter as generally for a problem there can be multiple. What matters is how can we do it in a smart way and that is where suggestion or rather I would say personal exp matters. Like using GSON with class mapping the way you showed makes my prob much simpler than unmarshalling data into raw json. Sorry to say this but I prefer suggestions over solutions and these suggestions are not `OP is asking for some tool or software types` :).